# Updating old column entries from new data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I am working on a problem. Here is an idea of what the original 60k row data frame looks like.

```
dataOne <- data.frame(
    marketVal = c(NA, 543534, NA, 115435, NA),
    bathrooms = c(3,3,2,3,5),
    garageSqFt = c(400, 385, 454, 534, 210),
    totalSqFT = c(NA, NA, 1231, 2232, 4564),
    units = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    subDivId = c("112", "111", "111", "111", "112"),
    ID = c(4,56,67,94,130) )
```

Some of the NA's for market value have been retrieved and stored in a new
data frame that looks like so:

```
dataTwo <- data.frame(
    marketVal = c(123123,234234),
    IDTwo = c(4,67) )
str(dataTwo)
dataOne$marketVal <- dataTwo$marketVal[match(dataTwo$ID, dataOne$ID)]
```

comparing ID's from both data frames I am attempting to replace the NA's in the first data frame with the market values in the second data frame. I've tried the match function as follows:

```
dataOne$marketValue <- dataTwo$marketValue[match(dataOne$ID, dataTwo$ID)]
```

but recieve an error "replacement has 2 rows, data has 5 calls". I fugured the fact these two data frames not being the same size wouldn't matter as we are only comparing the ID's found in either. How can I accomplish this efficiently considering around 4500 NA's need to be updated?

Comment: I cleaned up the declarations; it's so much more legible if you simply directly declare `dataOne <- data.frame(marketVal=c(...), bathrooms = c(...), ... , ID = c(...) )`. No need to declare all those temporary variables for each series and assign them unique names. Also allows you to name the `ID` column `ID`.

Comment: Essentially this is a question about merging (joining) two dataframes where there are some conflicts and we want to use the right-hand value (dataTwo). There are many duplicates on this.

Comment: @scmi: please provide links to duplicate questions so Pizza dude here can solve his issue. I personally don't think duplicates are a problem but I know it goes against the philosophy of SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method isn't working because it is producing a vector with 5 values: `1 NA 2 NA NA` which is longer than your `dataTwo` dataframe. Drop the NA values and your method would work.

This is how I would do it:

```
rowMatch <- which(dataOne$ID %in% dataTwo$ID)
dataOne[rowMatch, ]$marketVal <- dataTwo$marketVal
```

(Please note your `ID` variables were actually `IDOne` and `IDTwo` respectively in the example you'd provided.)

Comment: This relies on a special order of `dataTwo$ID`

Comment: Renu is correct, this relies that `dataTwo$ID` is sorted and matches the relative order of `dataOne$ID`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `merge`

```
require(tidyverse)    
new <- merge(dataOne, dataTwo, by.x = 'ID', by.y = 'IDTwo', all.x = T) 
new$marketVal <- new %$% coalesce(marketVal.x, marketVal.y)
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `safe_left_join` from my package [*safejoin*](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/safejoin), and "patch"
the matches from the rhs into the lhs when columns conflict.

```
# devtools::install_github("moodymudskipper/safejoin")
library(safejoin)
library(dplyr)

dataOne <- data.frame(
  marketVal = c(NA, 543534, NA, 115435, NA),
  bathrooms = c(3,3,2,3,5),
  garageSqFt = c(400, 385, 454, 534, 210),
  totalSqFT = c(NA, NA, 1231, 2232, 4564),
  units = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
  subDivId = c("112", "111", "111", "111", "112"),
  ID = c(4,56,67,94,130) )

dataTwo <- data.frame(
    marketVal = c(123123,234234),
    IDTwo = c(4,67) )

safe_left_join(dataOne, dataTwo, by=c(ID= "IDTwo"), conflict = "patch")
#   marketVal bathrooms garageSqFt totalSqFT units subDivId  ID
# 1    123123         3        400        NA     1      112   4
# 2    543534         3        385        NA     1      111  56
# 3    234234         2        454      1231     1      111  67
# 4    115435         3        534      2232     1      111  94
# 5        NA         5        210      4564     1      112 130
```

or for the same effect in this case we can use `dplyr::coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)
safe_left_join(dataOne, dataTwo, by=c(ID= "IDTwo"), conflict = coalesce)
```